# A question regarding Euler's number, Riemann's zeta function and the prime-number theorem

Tags: limits, logarithms, riemann-zeta, eulers-number-e

Consider now, that $\zeta(s)$ is Riemann's zeta function, such that:
$$\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty {1\over n^s}$$
Now, consider that the prime-number theorem states that:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} {\pi(x)\over x / \ln{x}}=1$$
Where $\pi$ is the prime-counting function. Now, consider the fact that Euler's number, $e$, can be written as:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} (1+{1\over n})^n=e$$
And now, consider that:
$$\pi(x)={x\over \log_{e_x}{x}}$$
Where $e_x$, is Euler's number at the $x$th order. Now, consider that if we were looking forward to calculating Euler's number based on the prime-counting function we can say that, (based on the prime-number theorem):
$$e_x=(\sqrt[x]{x})^{\pi(x)}\sim e$$
Now, we now, that as $x\rightarrow\infty$, $\sqrt[x]{x}\rightarrow 1$, and now, I want you to consider that this will be similar for a lot of functions. Say we have a function, $f(x)\subset\Bbb R$, (and with some other restraints), that as $x\rightarrow\infty$, $f(x)\rightarrow 1$, there will be a function, $g(x)$, such that:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)^{g(x)}=e$$
Now, what if, we let $f=\zeta$, we'd do so, because:
$$\lim_{s\to\infty}\zeta(s)=1$$
And now, we have that, for some $g$:
$$\lim_{s\to\infty}\zeta(s)^{g(s)}=e$$
In other words, my question is: what function, $g(s)$, satisfies the following?
$$g(s)\sim\log_{\zeta(s)}{e}$$

Comment: This essentially comes down to the fact that $\forall x>0,\,x^{1/\ln(x)}=e$, so unfortunately the resulting $g(s)$ does not have much to do with Riemann's zeta function.

Comment: @dxdydz It can have. You'd just have to find a better kind of function for $g$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can take $g(s)=1/\ln\zeta(s)\;$ ($s>1$).